# Confusing part in the introduction to algorithms

Tags: algorithm

> For example, when working with inputs of size n, we typically assume that integers are represented by c lg n bits for some constant c   1.

why do they assume it...? why c lg n...?
Sorry for asking very easy question. Thank you in advance.

Comment: what is the context

Comment: The data types in the RAM model are integer and floating point (for storing real numbers). Although we typically do not concern ourselves with precision in this book, in some applications precision is crucial. We also assume a limit on the size of each word of data. For example, when working with inputs of size n, we typ- ically assume that integers are represented by c lg n bits for some constant c   1.

Comment: this. it's such a difficult book isnt it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the `n` depends on the data you operate on. E.g. you have a value of `212`, the value of `lg n` will be `8` (or `9`). But this doesn't account for the actual data and machine type you operate on. It wouldn't be correct to assume that the word size is exactly `8 bits` here. The constant `c` is for the case where you're working with small inputs on a huge word-size machine. The added factor of `c` allows us to assume that the machine word size is at least `lg n`, but possibly a lot larger, without messing up the analysis.

To summarize `n` depends on the implementation independent numerical value. The amount of work a processor has to do for an operation does not depend on this value, but on how many bits are needed. Therefore the logarithm. The constant `c` refers to machine or implementation specific complexity.

Does that help?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. But still I dont get it. why 212 of lg n becomes 12? I thought i understand log but maybe not...
and I dont understand why that 12 means 12 bit.

Comment: 12 was just an example to make clear that there is a difference between numerical and machine precision.